# SQL inner join with max

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join, max, inner-join

I have an exercise on queries and I can't seem to find the solution to one of them. I have two tables : Aircrafts and Certified.

In the table Aircrafts I have the information AID (ID of the plane), Aname (Name of the plane) and Crusingrange(Max distance the plane have) :

```
AID    Aname       Crusingrange            
1     BoeingFr        25000   
2     BoeingUS        50000   
3      Jet01          3000  
4      Jet02          4000
```

In the table CERTIFIED I have this information AID (ID of the plane) and EID (ID of the pilot) :

```
AID    EID                   
1      199     
2      199  
1      110         
3      110        
3      109  
4      109
```

What I want is the ID of the pilot and the ID of the plane with the greatest cruising range he/she can fly.

```
EID    AID                   
199     2    
110     1  
109     4
```

I know I have to use MAX within INNER JOIN but I really don't find the solution and I have tried to break down my code but still impossible.

Thank you

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server ? Both are different RDBMS

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya for this question is doesn't really matter because the needed SQL is pretty general.. This pretty much coverd here on stackoverflow..

Comment: @RaymondNijland CruisingRange is in Airplanes table. OP needs to find the airplanes with max cruisingrange for an employee.

Comment: Yea @MadhurBhaiya never mind i didn't read `ID of the planes with the greatest cruising range he/she can fly.` the first time..

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server.  Which one is this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Firstly, get maximum value of `Crusingrange` for a `EID`, using `Join` and `Group By`. Use this result as a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html).
- Now, again **Join** back to the main tables using maximum value of `Crusingrange` and `EID`.

For MySQL, try the following:

```
SELECT c1.EID, 
       a1.AID
FROM CERTIFIED AS c1
JOIN Aircrafts AS a1 ON a1.AID = c1.AID 
JOIN        
(
  SELECT c.EID, 
         MAX(a.Crusingrange) AS Crusingrange 
  FROM CERTIFIED AS c
  JOIN Aircrafts AS a ON a.AID = c.AID 
  GROUP BY c.EID 
) AS dt ON dt.Crusingrange = a1.Crusingrange AND 
           dt.EID = c1.EID
```

Comment: thank you it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If your DB supports `row_number()` window function, then you can join your tables, then sort rows  per `EID` by Crusingrange, and choose longest ones:

```
SELECT EID, AID FROM (
    SELECT CERTIFIED.AID, CERTIFIED.EID, row_number() over(partition by CERTIFIED.EID ORDER BY Aircrafts.Crusingrange DESC) rn
    FROM CERTIFIED
    JOIN Aircrafts
    ON CERTIFIED.AID = Aircrafts.AID
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: "If your DB supports row_number() window function," For MySQL this query requires MySQL 8.0+ before it works..

Comment: @RaymondNijland - Yep, it's not clear which DB and version OP uses exactly, so I have "If your DB supports..."